# Google Cloud DNS Subdomain Mapping to Heroku

Tags: heroku, google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-dns

What I'm trying to do:
Map a subdomain hosted on Google Cloud to a Heroku app.

I'm used to dealing with different registrars and DNS providers. This is the first time I'm working on one that is hosted on Google Cloud.

With other DNS providers all I normally need to do is create the subdomain as a CNAME and point it to the Heroku DNS Target.

Example: 
mydomain.com points to website
subdomain.mydomain.com points to Heroku DNS Target

I have added a CNAME under the zone for the domain, but it does not seem to properly map to the app.

The domain registrar is GoDaddy, but it's now hosted on Google Cloud. I have access to the Cloud DNS through the Google Cloud Console, but not to Google Domains.

Most of what I've found as suggestions relates to the root domain. Some indicate that I may have to set up a separate forwarding zone for the subdomain. Other material indicates that the record needs to be set up via Google Domains. Not sure why it wouldn't work through Cloud DNS as a regular CNAME under the same zone as the root domain. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE - turns out you can do it the way I had done it. Although the TTL was set to 300, it can still take Google up to 48h to map a subdomain.